# push (redirect) to a route after successful login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

Till now I was redirecting to the User Dashboard from the React component, but I want to apply a different approach, I want to redirect after getting the success response from the saga itself.

For this, I have attempted to use `redux-first-history` (which comes with the support of react-router6) I have followed their documentation, almost everything is working but an action `@@router/CALL_HISTORY_METHOD` getting called twice.

Here are my routes

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Router history={history}>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<Layout />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<PublicPage />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
            <Route
              path="/protected"
              element={
                <RequireAuth>
                  <ProtectedPage />
                </RequireAuth>
              }
            />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

which goes across the project, below is my store.

```js
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from "redux";
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import rootReducer from "../store/reducers";
import { watchAuth } from "../store/sagas/index";
import { createReduxHistoryContext } from "redux-first-history";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const composeEnhancers =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
    ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
    : null || compose;

const { createReduxHistory, routerMiddleware } = createReduxHistoryContext({
  history: createBrowserHistory(),
  oldLocationChangePayload: true,
  showHistoryAction: true,
});
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const middleware = [sagaMiddleware, routerMiddleware];
const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
  whitelist: ["auth"],
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware)),
);
const persistor = persistStore(store);
sagaMiddleware.run(watchAuth);

export const history = createReduxHistory(store);
export default store;
export { persistor };
```

and my Saga

```js
import { call, delay, put } from "redux-saga/effects";
import axios from "../../../config/axios";
import {
  authFail,
  authStart,
  authSuccess,
  checkAuthTimeout,
  logout,
  logoutSucceed,
  setAlert,
} from "../../actions/auth/auth";
import { LOGIN_API } from "../../apiCollecitions";
import { push } from "redux-first-history";

export function* authLoginSaga(action) {
  yield put(authStart());

  const authData = {
    email: action.email,
    password: action.password,
  };
  try {
    const response = yield axios.post(
      `${LOGIN_API}?lng=${localStorage.getItem("i18nextLng")}&active=true`,
      authData,
    );
const expirationTokenTime = 3600;
    const expirationDate = yield new Date(new Date().getTime() + expirationTokenTime * 1000);
    yield localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
    yield localStorage.setItem("expirationDate", expirationDate);
    yield put(authSuccess(response.data.token));
    yield put(push("/protected")); //should redirect to the specified route
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(authFail(error.response.data.message));
  }
}
```

I have also set up a sample [GitHub](https://github.com/dextel2/react-private-routes-v6-example) repo for the same, for your reference.

Comment: `x expirationDate ` is undefined

Comment: @Alex I have added it, please check

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `router` key passed into `createStore`, as [specified in doc](https://github.com/salvoravida/redux-first-history#usage)?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do `window.location="/login"` if you don't want to complicate things or you can add a use *Redirect* from react-router and return this line from your return function

```
if(this.state.authSuccess)<Redirect to="/login" />
```

Comment: I used to do that, but I want to redirect via my saga